# Safari PDF viewer does not recognize referrer?

Tags: php, apache, pdf, .htaccess, safari

My goal is to have user-uploaded files (mostly PDF) available for download only via a link from the host website.

I've protected user-uploaded files with an .htaccess file that resides in the uploads directory.  .htaccess checks the referrer against the hard-coded domain name, and if the referrer matches, it allows access.  Otherwise access is denied.

This works fine, except when following the file links in Safari for PDFs.  Safari attempts to open them in-browser, and subsequently gets denied, even though the referrer was correct.

Any thoughts how to enable Safari users to view these files when coming from the correct location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Referer` (sic) header is very unreliable at best. When using it, I'd only disallow users with a blatently wrong referrer, 'referrerless' requests should go through as they might be perfectly legitimate.

You claim the referrer was correct, although Safari is blocked, and that's the only check you claim to do. Logically, the referrer is NOT correct: what's in your access and/or error log of apache?

I would solve it with a session (or pseudo session), or possibly even with creating temporary (empty) files based on remote ip-address, and base access on either existance of session, or existance of ip-related temporary file.

Comment: I would check session existence, but there isn't php code run between the clicking of the link and the opening of the file - in other words, if I check a session variable, I would have to do it in .htaccess, no?  Not sure if that's possible.

Comment: If you have the default file-based session, the session is named after the cookie. I think it might be possible to detect if a cookie-value exists as a file in the sesssion-dir. Takes some fiddling with SetEnv probably though.